# Does Java read 0xA0 as 0xFFFD?

Tags: java

One of my data processing modules crashed while reading ANSI input. Looking at the string in question using a hex viewer, there was a mysterious `0xA0` byte at the end of it.

Turns out this is 
[`Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/).

I tried replacing that:

```
String s = s.replace("\u00A0", "");
```

But it didn't work.

I then went and printed out what that character is using `charAt` and Java reports

```
65533
```

or `0xFFFD`
([`Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/))

Plugging that into the replace code, I finally got rid of it!

But why do I see an `0xA0` in the file, but Java reads it as `0xFFFD`?

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-8"));
 String line = r.readLine();
 while (line != null){
     // do stuff
     line = r.readLine();
  }
```

Comment: This is most likely related to character encoding, the behaviour could even be platform-specific. How do you read the input?

Comment: *How* the heck should anyone answer if you neglect to show/tell anything about how you transformed the input into a String?

Comment: @Durandal you assume I'm aware what is causing the problem to begin with. I've posted the file-reading code

Comment: @MxyL: No, you haven't - the only code you've included is the call to `String.replace`...

Comment: Oops, now it's there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`U+FFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) is the "Unicode replacement character", which is generally used to represent "some binary data which couldn't be decoded correctly in the encoding you were using". (Sometimes `?` is used for this instead, but U+FFFD is generally a better idea, as it's unambiguous.)

Its presence is usually a sign that you've tried to use the wrong encoding. You haven't specified which encoding you *were* using - or indeed how you were using it - but that's probably the problem. Check the encoding you're using and the encoding of the file. Be aware that "ANSI" isn't an encoding - there are *lots* of encodings which are known as ANSI encodings, and you'll need to pick the right one for your file.

Comment: Upvoted without actually reading the answer. Just because it's you. Cheers.

Comment: @Zabri: I'm pretty sure voting based on the user is the only way you _aren't_ allowed to vote.

Comment: It looks like the file originally was not UTF-8 and I was reading it as UTF-8. When I converted the file to UTF-8, it now correctly reports `0xA0`.

Answer (score 0):

How did you open the file? 
If you use `InputStreamReader(InputStream, CharSet)` your can specify the 'true' charset of the file you would like to open. If you do not specify the charset yourself, java is using the default charset of your platform. On unix this is often UTF8 while on windows its often ISO8859.